# (index):27 Uncaught ReferenceError: videojs is not defined

Tags: javascript, video.js

I am trying to create a javascript video application,i have added video js to my project and started using it.Now in my onload I'm trying to access videojs programatically and it is throwing Uncaught referenceError:videojs is not defined.
I'm new to javascript .
Attaching the code which I tried

```
  <head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />

   <!-- If you'd like to support IE8 (for Video.js versions prior to v7) -->
  <!-- <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/ie8/1.1.2/videojs-ie8.min.js"></script> -- 
  >
 </head>

   <body onLoad='getVersion()'>

 <video
id="my-video"
 class="video-js"
 controls
preload="auto"
width="640"
height="264"
poster="MY_VIDEO_POSTER.jpg"
data-setup="{}"
 >
<source src="MY_VIDEO.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
<source src="MY_VIDEO.webm" type="video/webm" />
<p class="vjs-no-js">
  To view this video please enable JavaScript, and consider upgrading to a
  web browser that
  <a href="https://videojs.com/html5-video-support/" target="_blank"
    >supports HTML5 video</a
  >
</p>
```

```
 <script>
  function getVersion(){
   console.log("videojs version : " + videojs.VERSION);
  var player = videojs('video');

  // Play through the playlist automatically.
  player.playlist.autoadvance(0);
 
 }
</script>
</body>
```

In the above code when im trying to call         var player = videojs('video');
I am getting the exception

Comment: You seem to have commented out the `<script>` that actually injects `videojs`?

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation you need **these two lines** at the top of your file to import `videojs`.

```html
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video.min.js"></script>
```

```js
console.log(videojs !== undefined)
console.log({"version": videojs.VERSION})
```

```html
<head>
  <link href="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video-js.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <script src="https://vjs.zencdn.net/7.11.4/video.min.js"></script>
</head>
```